# Obtener un objeto Java List<String> desde una petición Http de javascript

Tags: java, angularjs, json

Estoy trabajando con un *backend* con el *framework* Spring MVC, Tengo un servicio que toma un List que remueve algunos objetos de la base de datos. Cuando uso Postman envío el siguiente objeto JSON:

```
["ce8249aa-1ede-40b9-a158-d2c417c23df7",
"73a629b9-bae8-44aa-83c3-e8ee0fc96325",
"50c45e52-2c74-40ec-93e7-1b5379eae5db",
"c8a61e92-bc6d-47d0-a3e2-bda9ad85cecc"]
```

Luego cuando uso un servicio de Angularjs envío este objeto:

```
$scope.accounts = new Array("ce8249aa-1ede-40b9-a158-d2c417c23df7",
"73a629b9-bae8-44aa-83c3-e8ee0fc96325",
"50c45e52-2c74-40ec-93e7-1b5379eae5db",
"c8a61e92-bc6d-47d0-a3e2-bda9ad85cecc");
```

Pero obtengo el siguiente error:

> El requerimiento enviado por el cliente era sintácticamente incorrecto.

Este problema no ocurre con otros objetos JSON, por ejemplo:

Desde Postman:

```
{
    "accountName":"XxxxxXXxxxx",
    "paymentMethodMain":"Medio Pago",
    "accountType":"xx",
    "accountNumber":"123456AA"
}
```

Y desde Angular:

```
 $scope.account = {
     "accountName":"XxxxxXXxxxx",
     "paymentMethodMain":"Medio Pago",
     "accountType":"xx",
     "accountNumber":"123456AA"
};
```

En este caso todo funciona correctamente.

Comment: Hola, puedes mostrarnos el código donde haces el POST en angular?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lo que tu estas enviando es un arreglo, por lo que te manda ese error
podrias intentar lo siguiente

```
$scope.accounts = {
                     "datos":  ["ce8249aa-1ede-40b9-a158-d2c417c23df7",
                               "73a629b9-bae8-44aa-83c3-e8ee0fc96325",
                               "50c45e52-2c74-40ec-93e7-1b5379eae5db",
                               "c8a61e92-bc6d-47d0-a3e2-bda9ad85cecc"
                               ]
                   }
```

y ahora en $scope.accounts.datos tienes los valores que has enviado

Comment: Haciéndolo de esta forma obtengo el mismo error. Gracias.

Comment: podrias describir mas el error para ver que esta sucediendo